# SQL Server 2014: INSERT INTO values & subqueries

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I'm trying to insert values into 1 table by entering the values and getting 1 from a sub query, i'm not sure how to combine the STATIC VALUES for `SaleEventID, PoolName & CurrentUPB` with the SELECT statment that gives me value for `PoolID`

I will scale this up to include more columns where I could need to include additional select sub-queries.

What is the proper format?

```
SELECT DISTINCT [PoolID] 
FROM TESTLOANS
WHERE SaleEventID = 0
```

Tried combining them like this but it's not working.

```
INSERT INTO TESTPOOLS (SaleEventID, PoolID, PoolName, CurrentUPB)
VALUES ('55', [POOLID], 'SouthernFL', '45,000')

SELECT DISTINCT [PoolID] 
FROM TESTLOANS
WHERE SaleEventID = 55
```

UPDATE: now to return the CurrentUPB value I can use

```
SELECT SUM(CurrentUPB) CurrentUPB 
FROM TESTLOANS
WHERE SaleEventID = 0
```

If I have a few more of these type of select statements that give me the values for some of my INSERTS, How do I add those into the main query?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the `select` as-is and include the static values in the same statement.

```
INSERT INTO TESTPOOLS (SaleEventID, PoolID, PoolName, CurrentUPB)
SELECT DISTINCT '55', [POOLID], 'SouthernFL', '45,000'
FROM TESTLOANS
WHERE SaleEventID=0
```

Edit: Use window functions to get the counts or sums.

For eg:

```
INSERT INTO TESTPOOLS (SaleEventID, PoolID, PoolName, CurrentUPB,somecount)
SELECT DISTINCT '55', [POOLID], 'SouthernFL'
,sum(currentUPB) over(partition by poolid) --if you don't need the sum by poolid just use sum(currentUPB) over()
,count(*) over(partition by poolid) --if you don't need the count by poolid just use count(*) over()
FROM TESTLOANS
WHERE SaleEventID=0
```

Comment: If I need to add an additional select statement like `SELECT COUNT (*) NumberOfLoans
FROM TESTLOANS
WHERE SaleEventID=0` I just add that under the SELECT DISTINCT?

Comment: Thanks for your help and the explanations. Much appreciated!